Undelete an off-topic question that is linked externally?
This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334309/ecmascript-6-documentation-generators
is linked to from the esdoc documentation (https://esdoc.org/manual/faq.html under articles).
Should it be undeleted?

Esdoc should host the content itself, surely.

Considering that that question was deleted 6 years ago, Esdoc should also update their FAQ more regularly...

We don't undelete posts just because it is linked elsewhere. The question was closed and deleted for seeking recommendations for external resources so I don't think it should be undeleted.

Linking archive.org could be a quick-and-dirty solution: http://web.archive.org/web/20151030050400/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334309/ecmascript-6-documentation-generators

I've created https://github.com/esdoc/esdoc/pull/583 that links to web.archive.org.

Seems like a poor solution, if you ask me. Someone should write their own documentation, not rely on an archive of an off-site resource... It's basically the same idea as what "we" don't allow link only answers. There hasn't been a commit on that repo since April 2018 though; that's a common signal to tell you it's no longer maintained.

Once upon a time there was a hyper-linked web of information... I guess I'm getting old.

@thebjorn - You could propose changes to the deleted question, addressing the reasons, it was closed and deleted. You could the flag the question to be undeleted. Of course if the entire premise of the question isn’t within scope. The documentation should just be updated to not refer to a deleted question. It can’t contain important information otherwise the documentation would have been updated 6 years ago. 10 year old question asking for a list of generators that are 6 years old. It would serve no purpose to undelete that question

@thebjorn the old idea of the web for persistence of information had been demolished long, long ago. Stack Overflow is a web service, not a web server.

As the first close voter on this, I stand by the way I voted on it. It is clearly off topic.

@SecurityHound I don't think it's salvageable to be on-topic, unfortunately.  It solely asks for and is answered by tool recommendations; it's not asking how to do a task.

At most, it could perhaps be undeleted and have a historical lock (maybe along with deleting some of the less well-received answers?) if someone with subject-matter knowledge can verify that the content is useful, high-quality, and unlikely to become outdated, but...in general, it would be better if the docs were updated to host the content themselves, so that it can be maintained.

@RyanM - I know that, I made that clear, if the entire premise of the question is seeking a recommendation there is no fixing the question

@EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine the question it's definitely off topic today. The question is should information that has been useful (the question has a score of 48 and the top answer a score of 63) and has been linked to from external sources be resurrected "for the good of the web", or for "historical archives" or some similar reason?

@thebjorn So, you propose undeleting it and putting a historical lock on it?

@EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine less of a propose and more of a question. Personally I don't have any problems with outdated/historical information (I check the date on an issue to evaluate if it is relevant). It would perhaps be better than the current "Page not found"..? (there are SO questions that link to this page as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450188/jsdoc-3-template)

I am unable to actually see the post in question, but if the reason is solely "something links to it", then no.
